# Spring mongodb: How to make repositories work with the inheritance structure?

Tags: spring, mongodb

I have a collection that stores different documents representing instances of classes inheriting from the same abstract parent class. For each class I have a mongorepository defined as `MongoRepository<Volvo, String>` that was supposed to query all objects in the collecitons that belong to `_class` `com.repo.Volvo`.

However, it seems that the repository queries all documents, not only Volvos, and casts them to instances of Volvo.

How can I make it work with the _class definition, other than adding a filter by _class?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy solution is to have a collection for each derived class. Annotating each model with that concrete collection make sure that spring only fetches the concrete car model.

Consider the following example:

```kotlin
abstract class Car(
    @field:Id
    var id: String? = null,
    var model: String,
    var wheels: Int,
)
```

And two concrete models:

```kotlin
@Document(collection = "volvo")
class Volvo(
    id: String? = null,
    model: String,
    wheels: Int
) : Car(id, model, wheels)
```

```kotlin
@Document(collection = "vw")
class Vw(
    id: String? = null,
    model: String,
    wheels: Int
) : Car(id, model, wheels)
```

By defining a repository for each manufacturer querying each will be easy

```kotlin
interface VolvoRepository : MongoRepository<Volvo, String>
```

```kotlin
interface VwRepository : MongoRepository<Vw, String>
```

Now consider the following basic application wich adds some data into the database and reads then via injected reporitories:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application::class.java, *args)
}

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoRepositories
open class Application {
    @Bean
    open fun init(volvoRepository: VolvoRepository, vwRepository: VwRepository): CommandLineRunner = CommandLineRunner {
        volvoRepository.save(Volvo(model = "XC90", wheels = 4))
        vwRepository.save(Vw(model = "Golf", wheels = 4))

        println(volvoRepository.findAll().map { it::class.simpleName + " - " + it.id + " - " + it.model })
        println(vwRepository.findAll().map { it::class.simpleName + " - " + it.id + " - " + it.model })
    }
}
```

Result of those `println` calls are:

```
[Volvo - 62c5fb0798ab2c534dccaab0 - XC90]
[Vw - 62c5fb0898ab2c534dccaab1 - Golf]
```

Hope that this helps. If you would like to have this example code as working reporitory let me know.

### Edit 1: Another approach with just one collection

Having all cars within the same collection and present a repository interface with dedicated manufacturer accessor methods.

Models (`Volvo`, `Vw`) are the same as above

```kotlin
@Document(collection = "cars")
abstract class Car(
    @field:Id
    var id: String? = null,
    var model: String,
    var wheels: Int,
)
```

```kotlin
interface CarRepository : MongoRepository<Car, String> {

    @Query("{\"_class\": \"fqn.to.your.Volvo\"}")
    fun findVolvos(): List<Volvo>

    @Query("{\"_class\": \"fqn.to.your.Vw\"}")
    fun findVws(): List<Vw>
}
```

Using this sample application

```kotlin
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoRepositories
open class Application {
    @Bean
    open fun init(
        carRepository: CarRepository
    ): CommandLineRunner = CommandLineRunner {
        carRepository.save(Volvo(model = "XC90", wheels = 4))
        carRepository.save(Vw(model = "Golf", wheels = 4))

        println("Volvos")
        println(carRepository.findVolvos().map { it::class.simpleName + " - " + it.id + " - " + it.model })
        println("Vws")
        println(carRepository.findVws().map { it::class.simpleName + " - " + it.id + " - " + it.model })

        println("All cars")
        println(carRepository.findAll().map { it::class.simpleName + " - " + it.id + " - " + it.model })
    }
}
```

The following result is printed:

```
Volvos
[Volvo - 62c69a2c792f8b7c13f999a0 - XC90]
Vws
[Vw - 62c69a2d792f8b7c13f999a1 - Golf]
All cars
[Volvo - 62c69a2c792f8b7c13f999a0 - XC90, Vw - 62c69a2d792f8b7c13f999a1 - Golf]
```

Comment: I did not think about decoupling on the db schema. I will try out the idea, thank you!
I think that the main issue that may arise from this approach is that if I wanted to make an aggregated query for all Cars, I basically have to manually join all the repositories one after another.

Comment: You are still able to do that. When adding a `CarRepository` and next to it a `CarReporitoryImpl` you may add a method that provides an aggregated result returning all cars by using `$lookup` on both collections. Want an example?

Comment: Oh right, so I first make a method that returns an AggregatedQuery and then I do the actual query in the method body, thus only having to write the join once

Comment: That is one possible way. You may even implement methods to save cars by manually implementing those save methods and put them into the correct collection.

Comment: There is one last issue that arises with this implementation, which maybe you'll know a fix to. If I want to make aggregated queries, I have to make a MongoRepository<Car, String>, but that requires me to make Car not abstract. The issue is that when it's not abstract, the child classes find ambiguity in field naming, even if I add an "override" tag. Do you know how to work around this?

Comment: Ill try to find a way arround. Give me a minute :)

Comment: I've got it to work by basically making a dummy implementation data class CarImpl(): Car() and using that. Not the cleanest, but works

Comment: Sounds great. This may however be problematic in the future when trying to test for instance equalness ( `car is Volvo` ) will always return false. My attempt currently fails but i am trying :)

Comment: I added an alternative way of implementing it with just one collection. Maybe one of those two or a combined solution works best for you. Glad that i could help :)